# Write "A versus B" "A vs B" in Spanish?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, abreviaturas

In English I can write "A versus B" "A vs B" or "A vs. B".

Can I do the same in Spanish?

Also, English word "versus" is "versus" in Spanish?

Comment: You *can* use it, but it's generally recommended to use *contra* or *frente a*.  In what context?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spanish rules state that the correct abbreviation is **`vs.`** and not <strike>`vs`</strike> or <strike>`v.s.`</strike> as sometimes it is seen.

From [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=versus) you can read that it comes from latin and initially meant "towards" (*hacia* in Spanish) but later got the meaning of *against* (*contra*).

It means and it is spelled in the same way both in Spanish and English.

In Spanish it is widely used in writing especially on sports but as guifa pointed out in his comment when speaking we usually say "**contra**" or "**frente a**".

Answer (score 2):

RAE is not the same as Oxford. RAE provides rules in order to unify the Spanish spoken worldwide. You can read about it in the Wikipedia:
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Academia_Espa%C3%B1ola

Now, answering your question, the right way to abbreviate *versus* in Spanish is *vs.* http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/apendices/apendice2.html